# Modify rewrite slug of default category(taxonomy), wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change slug of default registered taxonomy, WordPress.

wordpress/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category = it lists the categories of posts.. and I want to change rewrite slug of these taxonomies like we generally do with custom taxonomies...

for example see below code of my custom taxonomy,

```
            add_rewrite_tag('%city_name%', '([^&/]+)');

            $rewrite_params = array(
                'slug' => 'm/%city_name%/jobs/categories',
                'with_front' => false
            );

            $labels = array(
                'name'              => __( 'Job Categories' ),
                'singular_name'     => __( 'Job Category' ),
                'search_items'      => __( 'Search Job Categories' ),
                'all_items'         => __( 'All Job Categories' ),
                'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Job Category' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Job Category:' ),
                'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Job Category' ), 
                'update_item'       => __( 'Update Job Category' ),
                'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Job Category' ),
                'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Job Category' ),
                'menu_name'         => __( 'Job Categories' ),
            );

            $capabilities = array(
                'manage_terms'      => 'manage_job_category',
                'edit_terms'        => 'edit_job_category',
                'delete_terms'      => 'delete_job_category',
                'assign_terms'      => 'assign_job_category'            
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels'            => $labels,
                'public'            => true,
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'query_var'         => true,
                'rewrite'           => $rewrite_params,
                'capabilities'      => $capabilities,                       
            );

            register_taxonomy( 'job_category', 'jobs', $args );
```

Here you can see I used %city_name% with slug, so i can find jobs inside city.. The same way i need to do with default posts.. So i can filter posts inside city according to this slug...

something like

```
           add_rewrite_tag('%city_name%', '([^&/]+)');

                $rewrite_params = array(
                    'slug' => '%city_name%/category',
                    'with_front' => false
                );
```

can anyone help me??